Worries about break of Computational graph and not supported for autograd
For some reason, when changing my loss function in torch, I have to use numpy's functions to compute. But I'm very worried about whether the use of numpy function would make the autograd function fail. I would really appreciate it if you can tell me when I have to care about the computational graph and when I don't.
In this codes I guess it won't influence.Here are my detailed code:
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_edt

class Distance_Loss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Distance_Loss, self).__init__()
        self.alpha = .6
        self.beta = .4

        self.MSELoss = nn.MSELoss()
    def forward(self, input, target):
        return MSELoss(torch.tensor(distance_transform_edt(input).cpu().numpy()), target)
# input may be the output of my own Network, target is my Ground -Truth

Or I really want to know that how can I check all grad property right!
If it would influence the grad, would following codes useful?
x_numpy = x.cpu().numpy()
x_restored = torch.from_numpy(x_numpy).to(x.device)
x_restored.requires_grad = x.requires_grad


Pytorch autograd only tracks pytorch operations. If you convert to numpy, you lose gradient tracking. Also this code: torch.tensor(distance_transform_edt(input).cpu().numpy()) is nonsense. You cast a tensor to numpy() then immediately recreate a tensor with torch.tensor. There is no reason to do that

That will definitely break the computational graph. Either you have to reimplement the transform function in pytorch or use write a custom autograd function to calculate the gradient manually.

@Karl @MinhNH Thank you all so much ,what if I just do the same operation to my ground-truth label, which I think is no need to record its grad. So the code is like this:  MSELoss(input, torch.tensor(distance_transform_edt(target)).cpu().numpy()) Would this code influence my computational graph?

torch.tensor(...).cpu().numpy() makes zero sense in context. What do you think you are accomplishing here?

Actually, my codes are: torch.tensor(tensor.cpu().numpy()). 'Cause there's a function only in numpy.

@DonalHuang if you only transform the label, then it's ok, though the code should be like MSELoss(input, torch.tensor(distance_transform_edt(target.cpu().numpy())), device = input.device) as  you will need to cast the label to numpy array first before parsing to the function, then casting back to pytorch tensor after that.
